# React Native (0.39.2) - Unknown named module error

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, import, react-native

```
React-Native "^0.39.2"
React "15.4.1"
```

I'm trying to `import` my custom component **Main.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
              <Text>
                Imported
              </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

within **index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Main from './app/components/Main'

export default class AppTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Main />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppTest', () => AppTest);
```

I don't understand why I got the error `unknown named module './app/components/Main'`, my project structure is correct:

```
AppTest
  |
  app
    |
    components
      |
      Main.jsx
```

Maybe I've wrong or forgot something very basic but can't figure out the cause

Comment: Can you show us your `Main.jsx`? Also, maybe the output of `tree -d <project root>`

Comment: You can see the file on top, the output is the same:├── app
│   └── components

Comment: I guess it's because of .jsx file extension - react native is not configured out of the box to ignore .jsx extension when importing. Try `import Main from './app/components/Main.jsx';` or rename your file to `Main.js`.

Comment: Worked! thank you man